# AssertionError: ({'errors': {'_schema': ['Invalid input type.']}}, 422) != {'Message': '

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking, flask-restful, marshmallow

This is the function I am trying to test.

```
def user_register():
    
    request_data = request.get_json()
  
    insert = service_register(request_data)
    
    print(type(insert))
    return insert
```

in this through service_register it passes to validation function for validating data

```
def service_register(request_data):
    
    print("Into Register")
    try:
        data_dict = validate_data(request_data)
    except ValidationError as errors:
        return{"errors": errors.messages}, 422
```

```
def validate_data(request_data):
    
    # request_data = request.get_json()
    print("data", request_data)
    get_data = user_schema.load(request_data)
    print("1111",type(get_data))
    return get_data
```

so while testing user_register() I'm getting this error

This is what I've done in testing

```
def test_service_reg_return_correct_data(self):

        data = {                                                              #dict
            "user_name": "testuser39",
            "password": "123456",
            "email_address":"testuser39@example.com",
            "dob": "2022-06-07 00:00:00",
            "address": "Ahmedabad",
            "uid": uuid.uuid4().hex
        }
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        m = mock.MagicMock()
        m.get_json.return_value = json_data
        print("m", m)
        with mock.patch("backened.routes.register.request", m):
            response =user_register()
            self.assertEqual(response, {'Message': 'New user Created'},201)
```

user_schema

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, validates, ValidationError, validate
import datetime



# User Schema
class UserSchema(Schema):
    print("Schema")
    
    user_name = fields.String(required= True, validate=validate.Length(min=5))
    password = fields.String(required = True)
    # email_address = fields.String(required=True, error_messages={"required": " email_address is required. "})
    email_address = fields.String()
    dob = fields.DateTime()
    address = fields.String()
    uid = fields.UUID(error_messages={'null': 'Sorry, Id field cannot be null',
                      'invalid_uuid': 'Sorry, Id field must be a valid UUID'})

    print("access")

    @validates('dob')
    def is_not_in_future(self, value):
        """'value' is the datetime parsed from time_created by marshmallow"""
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        if value > now:
            raise ValidationError("Can't create notes in the future!")
        # if the function doesn't raise an error, the check is considered passed

   

    class Meta:
        # Fields to show when sending data
        fields = ('id', 'user_name', 'password',
                  'email_address', 'dob', 'address', 'uid')
```

I've mocked request in user_register() and passed data in mock as shown in test case.

Comment: Well, yes - you mocked `request`, but not `get_json`, so it will return a mock. Instead of setting `m.data` you need to set `m.get_json.return_value`.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I've made the changes but now it is giving "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict"

Comment: Right, you have to encode your dict using `json.dumps`.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I've made the changes above in test function but now it's not accepting the input type n giving "AssertionError: ({'errors': {'_schema': ['Invalid input type.']}}, 422) != {'Message': '..."